# Position in 3D matrix

Tags: java, c++, algorithm

I have 3D data structure. In it I have values: 0 - n^3.
For example: If n = 3, then A[3][3][3] will contain values 0 - 26.

Now I want to know the position (i,j,k from A[][][]) of random value from 0 - 26 -> WITHOUT any loops and iterations.

For example if I give 1, the function should return me 0,0,1.

Can anyone help me with the problem ?

Comment: You can work it out with the basic arithmetic. The only think that you might be missing is the modulus `%` operator

Comment: im just curious how did you fit values from 0 to 27 to 3x3x3 matrix

Comment: What is the ordering of the values [0,27) in this array of arrays of arrays? You just gave one example 1 -> 0,0,1 and were not very specific about this.

Comment: @user902383 :  it should be 0 - 26 ! my bad.

Comment: @sellibitze:

A[][][] looks like this:
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8

9 10 11
12 13 14
15 16 17

18 19 20
21 22 23
24 25 26

when I give any number between 0 - 26 . it should return me its position in the matrix.

Comment: @Shardul: Since the array is three-dimensional, counting from 0 to 26 does not really answer my question. You have to do a much better job at explaining what it is that you want to know.

Comment: @sellibitze: Never mind, I got solution. By the way, I did not just "count" 0-26. I had written it in the matrix format.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use the remainder operator (`%`).  (e.g. `5 % 3 == 2`, `5 / 3 == 1`)

Comment: thanks for the hint. had to refine it to get a generic behavior. but was totally helpful.